# Migrating a WP site with 2 WP installations

Tags: multisite, migration

excuse me for posting a migration question here.
I am working with a client who has a website written in php and I am in the process of moving this site over to WP.
Currently in her root folder she has a folder named "blog" which is a WP installation, so for example www.website.com/blog will direct to the WP blog. This blog needs to remain untouched as I am only working on the main site.
Once I have finished the new WP site and migrated it over I need this blog folder to remain accessible with the same URL structure as before.
How would I go about this? Is it a simple case of backing everything up, migrating the new site over to her hosting and then copying this "blog" folder to the root of her main WP installation? Or am I missing something important here?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could combine everything into one WP installation. It wouldn't be too hard to have all the posts prepended with the `blog` directory, so their URLs would stay the same. You would basically do a bit of permalink setup and import the content from the blog site into the new site.

Or, you could run two separate WP installations. The user would have two separate sites with potentially two separate logins, which is often less than ideal, but you'd set up the new site on their hosting and just keep the `blog` folder intact. Anything inside the `blog` folder would be the original site and anything outside it would be the new site.